# Custom Font Complications (Wordpress)

Tags: plugins

I've been developing a site for a client who upon review wanted the font changed. I found a free plugin on line and added the font. There's an anomaly in my header as a result. Items in my menu aren't positioned next to each other. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error you are getting? **BTW:** using a plugin to add a font is just an "overkill".

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a separate plugin to change a font?

You should add the font directly in your theme's header and adjust the CSS accordingly.

For example, using Roboto from google fonts - https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Roboto:

In your theme's **header.php** add this line before `</head`>:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

In your theme's **style.css** add the font to your elements, as needed - for example:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

If you need more help understanding how this works, I think this resource could be a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started